# Configuring Django 1.7 and Python 3 on mac osx 10.9.x

Tags: python, django, macos, python-3.x

I have installed the latest versions of both django and python. The default "python" command is set to 2.7; if I want to use python 3, I have to type "python3".

Having to type "python3" and a django command causes problems. For example if I type: "python3 manage.py migrate" , I get an error. The error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in 
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'

Django does not seem to recognize my python 3. How do I get around this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install `django` for `python 3`, `pip3 install django`

Comment: That did the trick! I can now do: "python3 manage.py migrate", without any errors :)

Comment: Yep, you always have to install modules for python 2 and python 3 if you want to use them in both, glad it helped anyway.